# Change ::after and ::before styles with Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I change `::after` or `::before` styles with Javascript?

This is my code:

```js
var hh = document.querySelector('.ticket-right');
h = window.getComputedStyle(hh, "::after").getPropertyValue('top');
```

It returns top value. How can I change this value with Javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using javascript (or jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Comment: You can use CSS variables. See this answer, written by Temani Afif, in the linked thread above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/5526624